# How to Compare two JSON object Array and Get unique JSON objects from both array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have two arrays with objects and I want to compare them so I can get the objects  that are not in array one, and those not in array two.

For example, if I have following two arrays:

```
var arrayOne = [{ "name":"John", "age":30},{ "name":"John", "age":35},{ "name":"John", "age":35}];
var arrayTwo = [{ "name":"John", "age":35},{ "name":"John", "age":40}];
```

...I want to match in such a way so I can get two new arrays like `ResultOne` and `ResultTwo`:

```
var ResultOne = [{ "name":"John", "age":40}]; //JSON new in Array Two
var ResultTwo = [{ "name":"John", "age":35},{ "name":"John", "age":40}]; //JSON NOT IN array TWO but in Array One
```

I tried all Q&A suggested on Stack Overflow, but can't find a way to get the arrays when two objects are the same, like I have `{"name":"John", "age":35}` occuring two times in `arrayOne`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as base concept

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Now using for loop (Or any relevant ways) get each object in the array and compare.

Comment: Instead of answering, please vote as duplicate.